# Can one modify Fly mode in blender to be active on press/hold of a key?

Tags: customization

In the Unreal editor, when you hold down the RMB, you can use the mouse to rotate the camera and WASDQE to move around in 3D space. When you let go of the RMB you effectively deactivate Flight mode.

Can one set up something similar in blender? I have a gaming mouse with extra buttons so it would be handy to have a "activate on press" and "deactivate on release" for say the 4th mouse button in blender.

I find "Fly Mode" indispensable in other software but I find the activation and deactivation in blender to be really clumsy.

Is it possible to customize it the way that I'd want?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't know of any way to customize it the way you want.
But you can at least assign the command to your custom mouse button.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to open the **Blender User Preferences**. Go to the **Input** rider. You can edit the hotkeys in this context. Expand the 3D View > 3D View (Global) area.
   [image: Blender User Preferences Hotkeys]
2. Locate the **View Navigation** entry and change its hotkey to your mouse button.
   [image]

With the button you enter fly mode.

You *exit and confirm* with the left mouse button.

You *exit and abort* with right mouse button.

Lifting one button couldn't differentiate between those to actions.

Answer (score 1):

So this is apparently a dead topic, but I want to add my 2 cents for anyone that may come later with a similar questions.
You can set walk mode to activate on button press, as Leander mentions above, and in the 3D Walk Modal settings (found further down) set a confirm action to the release of the button. 
Mine is set to go into 'Walk' mode on Right Mouse Press, and confirms on Right mouse release. 
Works fine for my purposes, I can fly around with right mouse while it is held and as soon as I'm where I want to be I let go of right mouse and stay where I am to get work done. 
You will have to ensure that no other view controls are mapped to right though, rotate/move/zoom etc. unless they are using modifier keys.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to activate/disable fly mode to my knowledge is simply by using the hotkey <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: I use other 3D editing environments that use the WASD control interface. Unreal Editor as an example. I've found that it's the quickest and most intuitive way of navigating a 3D UI. I wish it was as easy and fast to access it as holding down the right mouse button is in UE4.